# Force the Spark Master to distribute code (not the submitter)

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to submit a spark job to a remote master from my notebook. I've got a local spark installation, so I can run

```
./bin/spark-submit --class "a.b.C" --master spark://198.51.100.1:7077 app.jar (...)
```

Due to firewall policy, nat, etc. I can reach the spark master (198.51.100.1) from my notebook (192.168.0.1), but not the other way around.

The problem is that my local spark installation tries to distribute code to the workers

```
SparkContext: Added JAR file:/path/to/app.jar at http://192.168.0.1:52605/jars/app.jar with timestamp 1439369933876
```

which must fail, because the workers have no route to my notebook

```
WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.0.1:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters.
```

So, how can I submit my application to the master **and** force the master to distribute my code to the workers?

Or did I get this all wrong and there's another reason for my problem here?

Answer (score 1):

You can upload you app.jar to a location that is visible inside you cluster (e.g. HDFS) and use cluster deploy mode when launching your app:

```
./bin/spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster .... hdfs://path/to.jar
```

See [Submitting Applications](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/submitting-applications.html) for more details.

Comment: not bad, but in case I don't want to upload my application to some remote server (because it frequently changes during development), is there any alternative?

Comment: For development you can use spark shell, local spark master, or a script that creates a jar file, uploads it somewhere and runs spark-submit automatically.

Comment: well, guess I have to live with a custom script then, if I want to test my application in a cluster environment. thanks for your reply!